# PHP script only works in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox

I have a code that works fine in Chrome browser but refuses to work in other browsers.

I would be glad for any advice on how to make it work not only for Chrome and what could be my mistake.

```
<?php
$geoplugin = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );
if ( is_numeric($geoplugin['geoplugin_latitude']) && is_numeric($geoplugin['geoplugin_longitude']) && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $lat = $geoplugin['geoplugin_latitude'];
    $long = $geoplugin['geoplugin_longitude'];
if ($geoplugin['geoplugin_countryCode'] == 'US') {
    echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Title</a>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the client. It works the same with any browser.

Comment: What is this doing wrong when you try to use it from another browser?

Comment: @Barmar I agree, but in Chrome I see a button that should be displayed when the given condition is met, and in other browsers this button is not.

Comment: Do you see it if you do `View Source`?

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately, no, I don't see the button in the Page Source in Firefox, but I see it in the Chrome page source

Comment: then the condition isn't being met. Use `var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $geoplugin);` to see the variable values, and compare them between the two browsers.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm curious. My guess is that one of the browsers is going through a proxy, so the locations are different.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, thank you. I've checked everything and figured out that the issue was in caching. It's funny that I didn't think to check the caching initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long clarification of the reasons why the code does not work, it turned out that the whole problem was in incorrect server caching.